# How to determine specific dll for 'using namespace' statement in C# dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am working on a class library that uses EpPlus and freeimage-dotnet-core nuget packages in **dotnet core 2.1**. But when i want to use `Image` object in my code the below error is shown:

> Error CS0433  The type 'Image' exists in both
>   'System.Drawing-dotnet-core, Version=1.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' and 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

EpPlus uses System.Drawing.Common dll and freeimage-dotnet-core uses System.Drawing-dotnet-core, because of that in my class library "system.drawing" namespace determined in 2 dlls.

I know it is possible to use '`extern alias xyz`', but it works on dotnet framework full version,not in dotnet core.
in Dotnet core projects, in visual studio we cannot see properties of a dll reference.

---

I solved the problem with adding an alias for one of my referenced libraries with this codes in .csproj file:

```
<Target Name="ChangeAliasesOfStrongNameAssemblies" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'System.Drawing-dotnet-core'">
        <Aliases>DrawingCore</Aliases>
      </ReferencePath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing-dotnet-core" Version="1.2.3" Alias="DrawingCore" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Thnanks to: @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: System.Drawing-dotnet-core is not a namespace name, is name of dll file. however in namespace names we cannot use "-" character. @Reniuz

Comment: Ah sorry misunderstood :)

Comment: The error message indicates you have the same object in two different namespaces and/or classes.  So the error can be fixed by references the namespace along with the class name.  Suppose you have Class1 in both Namespace 1 and Namespace2.   Then you use Namespace1.Class1  or Namespace2.Class1.

Comment: You could also alias the `Image` class and use the alias in your code: `using CoreImage  = System.Drawing-dotnet-core.Immage;`

Comment: BTW, those are `using` directives, not `using` statements. The latter are the things found inside method bodies being used to ensure clean-up of resources via `Dispose`.

Comment: @jdweng, the error indicates because 'One' object determined in same namespaces. And the same namespaces determined in different dll's which referenced in my project.

Comment: @JustinasMarozas , As i said in previews comment, we cannot use "-" in namespace names, and "System.Drawing-dotnet-core" is name of a dll reference not a namespace name.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, OK, but "using" is "directive" or "statement"?, it is not my problem. We are programmers, gaming with words is philosopher's job.

Comment: No, the C# language *defines* two of it's features that both use the `using` keyword. It *defines* one of them, the using directive, as something that logically brings namespaces into scope. It *defines* the other one of them, the using statement, as something that achieves resource cleanup. Using a pet name for something is sometimes okay but when you use a pet name that has a *specific* other meaning in the programming language you're working in, not so good.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Yes i know. thank you. I am reading your linked question.